# What could cause a generated hotspot to not consistently broadcast?

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I am running a variant of Debian on a Coral development board. When I generate a hotspot sometimes it becomes unavailable and then re-appears again as can be seen from my phone's wifi list and from viewing time graphs of SSIDs using the linssid program. Sometimes the signal goes down to 2 bars even though the board and my phone are right next to each other. What are some reasons it could drop out like this?

Here is the command I use to generate the SSID and its output:

```
$ sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
hotspot: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Using interface hotspot with hwaddr 00:0a:f5:89:89:82 and ssid "my_hotspot"
hotspot: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
hotspot: AP-ENABLED 
hotspot: IEEE 802.11 driver had channel switch: freq=2447, ht=1, vht_ch=0x0, offset=0, width=1 (20 MHz), cf1=2447, cf2=0
hotspot: STA 1e:f4:5e:60:19:d4 IEEE 802.11: associated
```

I don't see anything that indicates it is going down temporarily. Is there a command I can run to tell me more?

Here are the contents of `/etc/hostapd.conf`

```
#2.4GHz setup wifi 80211 b,g,n
interface=hotspot
driver=nl80211
ssid=my_hotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=8
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

#80211n - Change GB to your WiFi country code
country_code=US
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
```

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with this for a few more hours, I noticed that this `/etc/hostapd.conf` configuration was much better behaved:

```
interface=hotspot
driver=nl80211
ssid=my_hotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wme_enabled=1
ieee80211n=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```